# User input linked list

Tags: c++, pointers, data-structures, linked-list, insert

I'm trying to get user input to insert element in the linked list. It works if I try to add at 1st or 2nd position. Even though list has more than 3 element, if I put 3 in it, it never works and returns nothing showing no syntax error. Is it wrong use with variable or loop. I'm super confused.

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>

struct Node
{
    int data;
    Node *next;
};

Node *head;
void insert(int data, int n)
{
    Node* temp1 = new Node;
    temp1->data = data;
    temp1->next = NULL;
    if(n == 1)
    {
        temp1->next = head;
        head = temp1;
        return;
    }
    else{
        Node *temp2 = head;
        for(int i = 0; i = n - 2; i++)
        {
           temp2 = temp2->next;
        }
        temp1->next = temp2->next;
        temp2->next = temp1;
        return;
    }
    
}
void print()
{   
    Node *temp = head;
    while(temp != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d ", temp->data);
        temp = temp->next; 
    }
  
}

int main()
{   

    head = NULL;
    insert(3, 1);
    insert(33, 1);
    insert(384, 2);
    insert(384, 1);
    insert(432, 3);
    insert(34, 4);
    print();
}
```

Comment: `for(int i = 0; i = n - 2; i++)`, `=` is assignment not comparison

Comment: btw your code looks like C not C++. If you compile this as C++ then you should use the C++ headers `cstdlib` and `cstdio`, or rather make use of C++

Comment: wow thanks man!!! I was stuck there like 2 hours

Comment: Whatever resource you use to learn C++, it's not doing a very good job. Please invest in [some good books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282).

Comment: don't ignore compiler warnings: https://godbolt.org/z/74ePY95b7

Answer (score 0):

The obvious mistakes have been already elaborated in the comment. Something additional.

If this is intended to be C++, then you should also use C++ language, especially classes.

Then from your design. Please do not mix up the "Node" with the "Linked List". A node is a part of a linked list. It is contained within the linked list. And it should not be exposed to the outside world.

I you want to read a little bit about needed functionality of a linked list, then you may check the CPP reference. For example [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/forward_list)

And an example, from which you can take more ideas is listed below.

But first you need to read a book, this thing made out of real paper :-)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <algorithm>

// Very simple implementation of a forward list
template <class T>
class SinglyLinkedList {

    // The node
    struct Node {
        T data{};     // Data. Would normally be a templated argument
        Node* next{};   // And the pointer to the next node

        Node(const T& i, Node* n = nullptr) : data(i), next(n) {}; // Simple constructor to set a value and next pointer
    };

    Node* head{};       // This is the start of the list
    // It would be advisable to have a tail pointer. We use the more inefficient approach here
    Node* getLast() const { Node* n{ head }; while (n and n->next) n = n->next; return n; }

public:
    // Constructor / Destructor --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ~SinglyLinkedList() { clear(); }

    // Default constuctor
    SinglyLinkedList() {}   // Default

    // From an initialization list
    SinglyLinkedList(const std::initializer_list<T>& il) { clear();  for (const T& i : il) push_back(i); } // From initializer list

    // Copy constructor
    SinglyLinkedList(const SinglyLinkedList& other) { clear(); for (const T& i : other) push_back(i); }

    // Move constructor. Will steal the elements from the other 
    SinglyLinkedList(SinglyLinkedList&& other) noexcept { head = other.head; other.head = nullptr; }

    // Assignment operator
    SinglyLinkedList& operator = (const SinglyLinkedList& other) { clear(); for (const T& i : other) push_back(i); }

    // Move assignment operator 
    SinglyLinkedList& operator = (SinglyLinkedList&& other) { head = other.head; other.head = nullptr; }

    // Housekeeping --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    void clear() { Node* tmp{ head }; while (tmp) { Node* toDelete{ tmp }; tmp = tmp->next; delete toDelete; } head = nullptr; }
    int empty() const { return head == nullptr; }
    int size() const { int k{}; Node* n{ head }; while (n) { ++k; n = n->next; } return k; }

    // Modify content --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    void push_front(const T& i) { Node* n = new Node(i); n->next = head; head = n; };
    void push_back(const T& i) { Node* n = new Node(i); Node* l = getLast(); if (l) l->next = n; else head = n; }
    void pop_front() { if (head) { Node* tmp = head->next; delete head; head = tmp; } }
    void pop_back() { // This is a little bit more difficult in a singly linked list
        if (head) {
            Node* n{ head }, * previous{};
            while (n and n->next) {
                previous = n;
                n = n->next;
            }
            delete n;
            if (previous)
                previous->next = nullptr;
            else
                head->next = nullptr;
        }
    }

    // Access elements --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    T& front() const { return head ? head->data : 0; };
    T back() const { Node* n = getLast(); return n ? n->data : 0; }

    // Add iterator properties to class ---------------------------------------------------------------
    struct iterator {                           // Local class for iterator
        Node* iter{};                           // Iterator is basically a pointer to the node

        // Define alias names necessary for the iterator functionality
        using iterator_category = std::forward_iterator_tag;
        using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
        using value_type = T;
        using pointer = T*;
        using reference = T&;

        // Constructor
        iterator() {}
        iterator(Node* n) : iter(n) {}

        // Dereferencing
        reference operator *() const { return iter->data; }
        pointer operator ->() const { return &iter->data; }

        // Aithmetic operations
        iterator& operator ++() { if (iter) iter = iter->next; return *this; }
        iterator operator ++(int) { iterator temp{ *this }; ++* this; return temp; }
        iterator operator +(const difference_type& n) const { iterator temp{ *this };  difference_type k{ n }; while (k--)++temp; return temp; }
        iterator& operator +=(const difference_type& n) { difference_type k{ n }; while (k--)++* this; return *this; };

        // Comparison
        bool operator != (const iterator& other) const { return iter != other.iter; }
        bool operator == (const iterator& other) const { return iter == other.iter; }
        bool operator < (const iterator& other) const { return iter < other.iter; }
        bool operator > (const iterator& other) const { return iter > other.iter; }
        bool operator <= (const iterator& other) const { return iter <= other.iter; }
        bool operator >= (const iterator& other) const { return iter >= other.iter; }

        // Difference. Also complicated, because no random access
        difference_type operator-(const iterator& other) const {
            difference_type result{};
            Node* n{ iter };
            while (n and n != other.iter) {
                ++result;
                n = n->next;
            }
            return result;
        }
    };

    // Begin and end function to initialize an iterator
    iterator begin() const { return iterator(head); }
    iterator end() const { return iterator(); }

    // Functions typcical for forward lists ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Easy, becuase we can operate form the current iterator and do not need the "previous" element
    iterator insertAfter(iterator& pos, const T& i) {
        iterator result{};
        if (pos.iter and pos.iter->next) {
            Node* n = new Node(i, pos.iter->next);
            pos.iter->next = n;
            result = n;
        }
        return result;
    }
    iterator eraseAfter(iterator& pos) {
        iterator result{};
        if (pos.iter and pos.iter->next) {
            Node* tmp = pos.iter->next->next;
            delete pos.iter->next;
            pos.iter->next = tmp;
            result = pos.iter->next;
        }
        return result;
    }
};
// Test/Driver Code
int main() {

    // Example for initilizer list
    SinglyLinkedList<int> sllbase{ 5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15 };
    // Show move constructor
    SinglyLinkedList<int> sll(std::move(sllbase));

    // Add some values in the front
    sll.push_front(4);
    sll.push_front(3);
    sll.push_front(2);
    sll.push_front(1);

    // Delete 1st element (Number 1)
    sll.pop_front();
    // Delete last element
    sll.pop_back();

    // Use a std::algorithm on our custom linked list. Works because we have an interator
    SinglyLinkedList<int>::iterator iter = std::find(sll.begin(), sll.end(), 8);

    // Now add an element after 8
    iter = sll.insertAfter(iter, 88);
    // End delete the 9
    iter = sll.eraseAfter(iter);

    // Use range based for loop. Works because, we have iterators
    for (int i : sll)
        std::cout << i << ' ';

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is in this for loop

```
 for(int i = 0; i = n - 2; i++)
```

There is assignment operator(=) instead of equal to operator(==), also logic is wrong.

This is how it should be

```
#include<cstdlib>
#include<cstdio>

struct Node
{
    int data;
    Node *next;
};

Node *head;
void insert(int data, int n)
{
    Node* temp1 = new Node;
    temp1->data = data;
    temp1->next = NULL;
    if(n == 1)
    {
        temp1->next = head;
        head = temp1;
        return;
    }
    else{
        Node *temp2 = head;
        for(int i = 1; i < n - 1; i++)
        {
           temp2 = temp2->next;
        }
        temp1->next = temp2->next;
        temp2->next = temp1;
        return;
    }
    
}
void print()
{   
    Node *temp = head;
    while(temp != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d ", temp->data);
        temp = temp->next; 
    }
  
}

int main()
{   
    head = nullptr;
    insert(3, 1);
    insert(33, 1);
    insert(384, 2);
    insert(384, 1);
    insert(432, 3);
    insert(34, 4);
    print();
}
```